# How can I filter table rows based on field parameters in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

Assuming a Products table as such:

```
ID  Tags
1   Red; Blue; Green
2   Blue;Purple
3   Yellow
4   no color
```

In Power BI I have additional Boolean columns IsRed, IsBlue, etc, which are True if the Tags column contains the color. Example:

> IsBlue = CONTAINSSTRING(Products[Tags], "Blue")

I have field parameters as such:

```
ColorParameter = {
    ("Green", NAMEOF('Products'[IsGreen]), 0),
    ("Purple", NAMEOF('Products'[IsPurple]), 1),
    ("Blue", NAMEOF('Products'[IsBlue]), 2),
    ("Red", NAMEOF('Products'[IsRed]), 3),
    ("Yellow", NAMEOF('Products'[IsYellow]), 4)
}
```

Problem: the table in Power BI with the Products Table and the Parameter is showing all records, regardless of the values for the selected parameters. How can I show only the rows with True for the selected color?

[image: Data]

Ideally I wouldn't need to show any of the Boolean columns on the table, but I think it might be required, since I need to link the parameter to it somehow.

[pbix file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZThKMlEQkhd8fZP04pHfRqQDOI1bOvas/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for your sample data.

Create a measure as follows:

```
Measure = 
VAR a  = IF( CONTAINS(VALUES(ColorParameter), ColorParameter[Color], "Green" ) && TRUE() IN VALUES(Products[IsGreen]), 1)
VAR b  = IF( CONTAINS(VALUES(ColorParameter), ColorParameter[Color], "Purple" ) && TRUE() IN VALUES(Products[IsPurple]), 1)
VAR c  = IF( CONTAINS(VALUES(ColorParameter), ColorParameter[Color], "Blue" ) && TRUE() IN VALUES(Products[IsBlue]), 1)
VAR d  = IF( CONTAINS(VALUES(ColorParameter), ColorParameter[Color], "Red" ) && TRUE() IN VALUES(Products[IsRed]), 1)
VAR e  = IF( CONTAINS(VALUES(ColorParameter), ColorParameter[Color], "Yellow" ) && TRUE() IN VALUES(Products[IsYellow]), 1)

RETURN a+b+c+d+e
```

Add it to the table (you can hide the column if you don't want to show it).

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]